# SonarQube server is not reachable from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

I have a separate server for SonarQube (10.xx.xx.999). Whenever I run the build pipeline in Jenkins it kicks off SonarQube scan. The Jenkins master dispatches this job to a slave that is a Windows agent for .NET app and runs the sonar scanner using MSBuild via Jenkinsfile. The issue here is that the build job is not able to reach the SonarQube server.
The console output shows Downloading from http://xx.x.xx.999:9000/api/server/version... and throws 503 error.

The interesting thing is I tried Test-NetConnection in the Jenkins slave via Powershell, connection succeeded. The ping and curl also works as well. I also browsed the http://xx.x.xx.999:9000/api/server/version, and it works in the Jenkins slave. I was able to perform a sonar scan via the command line from the Jenkins slave.

Comment: Is the slave Jenkins Window agent running as a local account that doesn't have network permissions?

Comment: No, all our servers are hosted in AWS. SonarQube server is running on RHEL. Jenkins slave machine was able to reach out to this machine when I ran sonarscanner. The issue is when I ran the scan via the Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: When the pipeline agent runs the scan, do you know what user account is used? When you tested running the scan from the command line, was it the same or a different user? Is the Jenkins agent on Windows running under the local SYSTEM user account? The local SYSTEM user has no network access.

Comment: I just copy/pasted the same script I use in the Jenkins pipeline (jenkinsfile), so the username and password are the same. No, the Jenkins slave is not running under the local SYSTEM user account.